# Normal probability plot for LogNormal and Weibul data in python

Tags: python-3.x, statistics, probability, probability-distribution

checking [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46127030/how-to-use-python-to-draw-a-normal-probability-plot-by-using-certain-column-data)  I was wondering , If I have defined my lognormal plot already, then how would I draw the normal probability plot for my lognormal data ? should the x be defined the same way in the mentioned code ?

This is my data = [336256, 620316, 958846, 1007830, 1080401]

This is where I plot my Weibul and lognormal  : [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51634119/python-keeps-overwriting-hist-on-previous-plot-but-doesnt-save-it-with-the-desi/51648079?noredirect=1#comment90260012_51648079)

In my code, this is what I get for Lognormal normal probability plot

[image: lognormal]

and what I get for Weibull normal probability plot :

[image: Weibul]

The problem with these curves is that they are too Linear !!

The are supposed to be this way :
The other difference is that I need to place my points between 0 and 100 and they should not be equally spaced 
[image: logweib]

also I am not sure at which confidence interval I am working in my own code.

Update 1 :

Using [the code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382612/python-equivalent-for-matlabs-normplot)

I get these results :

[image: Lognormal]

for  weibull

[image: weibull]

Comment: Your question does not seem to be about programming, you might have a better chance at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I have already done that, they told me exactly the same thing and proposed stackoverflow.com, anyways I think it suits both, depends who has worked both

Comment: Ok, for me your question is not fully clear, e.g. what do you mean by this: "Weibull normal probability plot", I think something is missing or messed up here. Your data is only 5 values yet you have a lot of dots on your plots. How come?

Comment: Ok, let go of the first couple of images, the second couple is what I should replicate, those are done in mini tab, what is done is basically you calculate a weibull and lognormal distribution and to see which one is fit better, a normal plot is calculated. I tried to do the same, but for x axis I produced 10, 000 points